# Sort array of categories by root category first

Tags: php

I would like sort a given array of categories. The root categories must appear first before their child categories in a new array.

Example data:

```
$data = [
  ['id' => '1', 'name' => 'abc', 'parent_id' => '0' ],
  ['id' => '4', 'name' => 'def', 'parent_id' => '5' ],
  ['id' => '3', 'name' => 'ghj', 'parent_id' => '2' ],
  ['id' => '5', 'name' => 'zst', 'parent_id' => '1' ],
  ['id' => '2', 'name' => 'klm', 'parent_id' => '1' ],
];
```

Output I would like to achieve:

```
$output = [
  '1' => ['id' => '1', 'name' => 'abc', 'parent_id' => '0' ],
  '5' => ['id' => '5', 'name' => 'zst', 'parent_id' => '1' ],
  '4' => ['id' => '4', 'name' => 'def', 'parent_id' => '5' ],
  '2' => ['id' => '2', 'name' => 'klm', 'parent_id' => '1' ],
  '3' => ['id' => '3', 'name' => 'ghj', 'parent_id' => '2' ],
];
```

My code until now:

```
function sortCategories($data) {
  $output = [];
  foreach ($data as $category) {
    if ($output[$category['id']] || $output[$category['parent_id']])
      continue;

    if (!$output[$category['parent_id']])
      $output = getParentCategories($category, $ouput, $data);

    $output[$category['id']] = [
      'id' => $category['id'],
      'name' => $category['name'],
      'parent_id' => $category['parent_id']
    ];
  }
  return $output;
}

function getParentCategories($category, $output, $data) {
  if ($output[$category['parent_id']]) {
    return $output;
  } else {
  }
}
```

The problem I have is that I don't know how to probably implement getParentCategories() so that this function handles root categories the right way.

Any suggestions how to solve the problem?

Comment: @Anant or even shorter: https://eval.in/599831

Comment: unfortunately not. Because I can't sort the array by parent_id.

Comment: Could you clarify `root` and `child`. Maybe drop these words and use `parent_id` and `id` (or the inverse, that is the possible confusion) instead. Good practice in IT is to avoid synonyms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using `foreach()` will work for you:-

```
<?php 
$data = [
  ['id' => '1', 'name' => 'abc', 'parent_id' => '0' ],
  ['id' => '4', 'name' => 'def', 'parent_id' => '5' ],
  ['id' => '3', 'name' => 'ghj', 'parent_id' => '2' ],
  ['id' => '5', 'name' => 'zst', 'parent_id' => '1' ],
  ['id' => '2', 'name' => 'klm', 'parent_id' => '1' ],
]; // original array

$new_array = array(); // new empty array

foreach($data as $key=>$value){ // iterate through original array
    if($value['parent_id'] == 0){ // check root value
        $new_array[$value['id']] = $value; // assign full sub-array to newly created array
    }else{ // if not root value
        $get_key = searchForId($value['parent_id'],$data); // based on parent-id get the parent array key from original array
            $new_array[$data[$get_key]['id']] = $data[$get_key]; // based on key assign parent array to the newly created array
            $new_array[$value['id']] = $value; // assign the child array to newly created array
    }

}
function searchForId($id, $array) { // send parent_id and original array
   foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
       if ($val['id'] === $id) {
           return $key; // return key of parent id
       }
   }
   return null;
}
echo "<pre/>";print_r($new_array); // print new array
?>
```

Output:- https://eval.in/599837

Comment: Your explanation helped me a lot about understanding the real problem I was trying to solve. Just played around a bit and gotta solved that myself with a different solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Bene  you are welcome. I think this code is also sort+clean

Answer (score 1):

Since php 7 we can use the *spaceship* operator like this

```
usort($output, function ($a,$b) {
   return $a['parent_id'].$a['id'] <=> $b['parent_id'].$b['id'];
});
```

Both id's are concatenated so that `id` and `parent_id` are sorted and `parent_id` has priority over `id`.

In a real case, the `id`'s may have a range > 0..9 and you want 5 < 12, which is not the case when comparing strings as in the code above. Maybe you can post a code that takes that into account and have us review it. Maybe also learn about the difference between `'1' => ['id' => '1']` and `1 => ['id' => 1]` first.

Comment: But what about older version. I tested your code for php5.514 and it not worked.

Comment: @Anant I would like to give you the exercise to convert that.

Comment: Not to me, to OP. Because may be he/she needed that (because of older version)

Comment: @Anant oops, sorry.